# xcode3 xcode4 project file sharing?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, project, xcode3to4

I'm sharing xcode4 project through svn.

Wonder if it'll be ok for another user to use xcode3.
I read xcode3 and xcode4 can read the same project file.
However, when you share the project file using svn file, it's a bit different story.
(Mainly I'm(with xcode4) worried of possibilities that I'll have to rebuild project on every other person(with xcode3)'s commit or vice versa)

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this already at it was no problem. Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 are using the same formats, only the interfaces differe.

Answer (score 2):

From [XCode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/NewProject/NewProject.html)

> Xcode 4 can open an Xcode 3 project
>   without difficulty. You can open the
>   project in any of the usual ways:
>   Control-click the project and choose
>   Xcode 4, drag the project onto the
>   Xcode 4 icon, or choose File > Open to
>   open the project. You can have both
>   Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 installed on your
>   system at the same time without
>   conflict. You can open a project in
>   either program, save it, then open it
>   in the other program without
>   invalidating the project or losing any
>   data.
>
> Xcode 4 reads and builds projects
>   created in Xcode 2.1 through the
>   latest release of Xcode 3. Projects
>   created with Xcode 4 can be opened and
>   built on Xcode 3.2 and later.
>
> Opening and building a project in
>   Xcode 4 does not upgrade or alter it.
>   **Changes you make to a project in Xcode
>   4 remain compatible with earlier
>   versions of Xcode**.

Answer (score 1):

General interoperability works fine. But if you use Xcode 4's integrated unit testing (running "application tests" in the simulator), those won't work in Xcode 3.